# Laravel Sanctum auth:sanctum middleware with Angular SPA unauthenticated response

Tags: php, angular, laravel, laravel-sanctum

I have an application that has the following setup:

**Laravel**

Host: appname.local:8000

Environment variables:

- SESSION_DRIVER=database
- SESSION_LIFETIME=480
- SESSION_CONNECTION=mysql
- SESSION_DOMAIN=.appname.local
- SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE=false
- SESSION_COOKIE=appnameapi_session
- SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS='.appname.local,localhost,127.0.0.1'

**Angular**

Host: appname.local:4200

**What works at the moment:**

- I can call Sanctum's csrf-cookie endpoint which sets the CSRF token in my browser.
- I then can call my API's login endpoint to authenticate the user in my Laravel app using Auth::attempt(). This create a new entry in the sessions table as seen below

*Angular methods to get token and authenticate user*
[image: Angular methods to get token and login]

*Session database entry after successful authentication*
[image: Session database entry after successful authentication]

**What does not work:**

Subsequent requests to routes that are protected by the following middleware: **auth:sanctum** all result in unauthenticated responses. The HTTP requests never make it to my controllers.

*auth:sanctum protected routes*
[image: auth:sanctum protected routes]

But I can see in the developer's console that the cookies are being sent. So I don't understand why Sanctum isn't picking up the auth
[image]

I've followed several tutorials and I can't seem to understand why Laravel's Authenticate middleware is unable to see that I've already authenticated my user.

Does anyone know what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Have you double checked you have all the settings correct as shown in the [SPA configuration](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/sanctum#spa-configuration) section?

Comment: @DigitalDrifter Yes, I did. Stateful configuration takes the value of my env variable 'SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS' that I posted in my question. I added sanctum's middleware to the API group and I also completed the CORS & Cookies section as suggested in the docs.

Comment: hi. did you manage to resolve this? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: @EdenWebStudio Nope. I decided to use normal session based auth for now. I plan to try again once I clear some of my tasks.

Comment: @EdenWebStudio did you manage to solve this? I'm stuck there too :(

Comment: @zinyando have you got exact same config?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answers provided by @agm1984 and @Eden Webstudio were quite useful. However, they did not solve my issue.

After additional debugging, I noticed that sanctum's guard logic looks for a guard in 
`config/sanctum.php`. Its default value is **web**. My default guard for the protected routes is the **api** guard which is the guard that I used during the authentication process.
[image]

After setting the guard key in config/sanctum.php with 'api' the authentication seems to be working smoothly. To be honest, I can't remember why I decided to the session driver for my api guard.

**config/sanctum.php**
[image: config/sanctum.php]

**config/auth.php**

[image: config/auth.php]

Answer (score 3):

Laravel Sanctum doesn't appear to support wildcard domains for the SPA.

Try removing the dot.

```
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS='appname.local'
```

You may need a different solution for wildcard subdomains. You could look at bearer token option. I haven't tested this though.

Answer (score 3):

I think Eden is correct. I'm visiting this question for unrelated reasons, but to support subdomains, you can have a dot in `SESSION_DOMAIN` env variable, but never `SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS`.

Here is a valid env config for both local and production:

**./.env**

```sh
# localhost
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS="angular-site.test"
SESSION_DOMAIN=".angular-site.test"

# production
# SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS="hockeysticks.net"
# SESSION_DOMAIN=".hockeysticks.net"
```

That will allow the cookies to work across multiple subdomains such as `auth.hockeysticks.net`, `product.hockeysticks.net`, `service.hockeysticks.net`, and `api.hockeysticks.net`.

If a person puts the dot in `SESSION_DOMAIN`, cookies will still work if there are no subdomains, but it should be theoretically more secure to omit it in that case.

Here is a video by Mohamed Said, a developer at Laravel, talking about Sanctum: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kd3hcrxtTHA. In it, he walks through the authentication logic.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I found the sanctum SPA API works fine if the request is made from an app not set on a port no.

you can host your frontend app on

> appname.local

instead of appname.local:4200

Answer (score 0):

If you are using localhost for your frontend and backend with different ports like the following:

**Angular/Ionic**

> Host: localhost:8100

**Laravel v8**

> Host: localhost:8000

Try setting your **./env** to:

```
SESSION_DOMAIN=localhost
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost:8100
```

Keep in mind, I've set the following after following @Gloire 's answer