# Laravel Sanctum not authenticating when both api and SPA are on subdomains

Tags: php, laravel

I have been trying to get subdomains working with Laravel Sanctum for about 2 hours tonight, I had it working when my SPA was at `app.domain.com` and my api was at `domain.com` but now I need to move the api to be hosted at `api.domain.com` but for whatever reason when both the `session_domain` and the `sateful_domain` are subdomains things get all wacky. Wondering if anyone has had similar issues. Can't find anything helpful online either.

**.env file**

```
SESSION_DRIVER=cookie
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE=true
SESSION_DOMAIN=.domain.com
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=app.domain.com
```

**config/cors.php**

```
'paths' => ['api/*', 'login', 'logout', 'register', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],

'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

'exposed_headers' => [],

'max_age' => 0,

'supports_credentials' => true,
```

**Kernel.php**

```
'api' => [
            \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
            'throttle:api',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class
        ],
```

CSRF protection is working fine, and I am able to "login" but any request after the successful login 401's and every time I login again another cookie is added to the browser.
I have followed everything on the laravel docs, would love some help here if someone has the time / has ran into this before

All of my api routes are guarded with  `Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:sanctum']`

I have even tried the findings from this post and still no dice.

[Laravel Sanctum auth:sanctum middleware with Angular SPA unauthenticated response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61160012/laravel-sanctum-authsanctum-middleware-with-angular-spa-unauthenticated-respons)